# NSMutableDictionary objectForKey: returning NULL from a full dictionary

Tags: null, nsmutabledictionary

I hope someone can explain where I am going wrong with this extremely frustrating, but apparently simple issue, which I have done many times elsewhere, but has defeated me, despite pouring over all the SO questions on this topic.

I am instantiating an NSMutable dictionary in viewDidLoad,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

// more code here
    }

Then populating the dictionary with,

```
[self.myDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:holidayDays] forKey:[self.holidayInfo objectForKey:@"days"]];
```

But when I try and get the values for particular keys, they are returning NULL,

```
    - (void) processHolidayLoop:(int)i forAKey:(NSString *)aKey using:(UIManagedDocument *)document
    {
        if ([self.myDictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {  NSLog(@"YES IT DOES");}
        int hDays = [[self.myDictionary objectForKey:aKey] intValue];
        NSLog(@"aKey is %@", aKey);
        NSLog(@"hDays is %d", hDays);
        NSLog(@"myDictionary valueForKey: is %@", [[self.myDictionary objectForKey:aKey] description]);

// more code here
    }
```

The above code NSLogs, YES IT DOES, the aKey correctly, but gives "hDays is (null)" and "myDictionary valueForKey: is (null)" when it is called from another method,

```
NSString *aKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"holiday%d", j ];
[self processHolidayLoop:i forAKey:aKey using:self.document];
```

I have checked the values and keys in self.myDictionary using the following method and I have confirmed that the dictionary is correctly populated with all it's keys and values.

```
- (void) describeDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSArray *keys;
    int i, count;
    id key, value;

    keys = [dict allKeys];
    count = [keys count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
        value = [dict objectForKey: key];
        NSLog (@"Key: %@ has value: %@", key, value);
    }
}
```

I have looked through all the SO answers on this one and tried many different ways of solving this, but I can't get it to work. I am sure I am missing something very obvious, but I need someone else to see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I bet you are not passing the same keys that you used to fill the ``NSMutableDictionary``. Also, if this ``[self.holidayInfo objectForKey:@"days"]`` is as you typed, you are setting the same key to all the objects.

Comment: Sorry amb, I have just edited my post to show how I am passing the keys to the method. The key @"days" is the key in another dictionary that changes for different holidays. That part seems to work OK, because using the describeDictionary: shown above, I am able to see that all the keys and values are correct. The aKey is a simple NSString that corresponds with the myDictionary key. The NSLog apprears to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if ([self.myDictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {  NSLog(@"YES IT DOES");}
```

will always be true, because `NSMutableDictionary` implements `objectForKey:`.

The `aKey` will always log correctly, because you're passing it in to your method.

If you want to see if the dictionary contains a specific key, you should do this:

```
if([self.myDictionary objectForKey:aKey]) {
    // Do your processing here
}
```

If this code never executes, then the key is not contained in the dictionary. I'd suggest iterating through `allKeys`, and use `isEqual:` to determine exactly what the issue is. If you log both sides of the comparison, the root cause should be clear.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have added that conditional to my code and the statement is never TRUE, but from my code, can you tell me why the dictionary appears full using the describeDictionary method but doesn't respond to objectForKey:aKey method?

Comment: The simple answer is that `aKey` is not a key in the dictionary. Perhaps you could try iterating through `allKeys`, printing each key out, and then printing out the comparison between it and `aKey`. A bit basic, but should indicate which key you're expecting to match that doesn't.

Comment: @Chuckly your problem is that you are not passing the same keys when you're accessing the dictionary. Try printing ``allKeys`` as @paulbailey suggested and review the way you access your dictionary.

Comment: Well, it is very curious but the key does seem to be there from the describe dictionary I get - 2013-11-14 13:39:08.382 TRHoliday[1662:907] Key: DASJ has value: 14   and  aKey gives  -   2013-11-14 13:39:08.666 TRHoliday[1662:907] aKey is DASJ

Comment: There's not a rogue space or something is there? What does calling `isEqual:` give?

Comment: I don't believe it. I feel such a moron; defeated for so long by trailing whitespace! Thank you so much for solving this for me. How do  I tick your last comment rather than the first suggestion as that was really the solution to this headache?